# Probability of 2 or more students from a group of 5 being on the same team of 6 in a class of 36

Tags: combinatorics

To clarify the title:
There is a class of 36 which is to be divided into 6 teams of 6. There are 5 specific students of interest, and I want to figure out the probability of 2 or more of those 5 being on the same team.

I know there are other questions like this, but I’ve tried to use multiple methods to do this and keep getting different answers so I’m clearly doing something wrong.

I started by trying this:

$$\frac{6*5*4*3*2}{36*35*34*33*32} + \frac{6*5*4*3}{36*35*34*33} + \frac{6*5*4}{36*35*34} + \frac{6*5}{36*35}$$

I got around 19.35%.

Then, I tried this because I thought maybe the first team member can go anywhere so the 6/36 is unnecessary:

$$\frac{5*4*3*2}{35*34*33*32} + \frac{5*4*3}{35*34*33} + \frac{5*4}{35*34} + \frac{5}{35}$$

I got 16.13%.

Then, I tried to modify a method I saw in a similar answer like so:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{5} \frac{_{36-n}C_{6-n}}{_{36}C_{6}}$$

I got 2.69%.

Yeah, I really don't remember how this works...

Comment: Can you show us one of your attempts and answers by editing your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want the probability that the specified students are not all on different teams. This is simply the compliment $(1-p)$ of the probability that they are all on different teams.

$$P(\text{all different teams})=\frac{36}{36}\times\frac{30}{35}\times\frac{24}{34}\times\frac{18}{33}\times\frac{12}{32}=\frac{162}{1309}\approx12.4\%$$

$$P(\text{not all different teams})=1-\frac{162}{1309}=\frac{1147}{1309}\approx87.6\%$$

Comment: To emphasize, this does do a good job of answering the presumably originally intended question of the probability there are at least two of our special students together... however it does not answer the question in the title of there being a group of exactly $k$ students together (*which admittedly, answering for exactly $k$ is a very poor approach to what is probably the intended original question but is still an interesting question in its own right*)

Comment: @JMoravitz The title is asking for a singular probability, and defines a set of conditions qualifying an event. That said, I certainly understand the ambiguous nature of the wording. The clarification in the body should eliminate any confusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, my mistake. I'm just not sure how else to say it. The title would've gotten too long if I tried to phrase it like the body.